# Run each function after Ajax content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a an Ajax function that is used multiple times. I am using this function to be added to a click event to load content into the side drawer.

```
$( ".link" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    loadSideDrawerContent($(this).attr('href'), 'middle', true, imageSuperZoom);
    openSideDrawer('middle');
});
```

Now the **loadSideDrawerContent** is a simple Ajax call that fetches html content and stores it within a div.

**Problem:**

I am trying to run a separate function that works on ready() load but not when content is loaded.

```
$( ".link" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    loadSideDrawerContent($(this).attr('href'), 'middle', true, imageSuperZoom);
    openSideDrawer('middle');

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        if (typeof resizeImage == 'function') { 
            console.log('it exists');
            resizeImage(); 
        }else{
            console.log('it doesnt');
        }
    });

});
```

I have tried the following but i have no success. The function does exist but it doesnt fire off.

EDIT: Resize function (note: this works fine on the ready call - just not after the content is loaded)

```
function resizeImage(){
    $mage_resize.each(function () {

        var element = jq(this), 
            src = jq(this).attr('src'),
            regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g,
            currentWidth,
            newWidth,
            newSrc = {};

        if ($(window).width() > 1824) {

            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(2000/2));

        } else if (jq(window).width() <= 1824 && jq(window).width() > 1366) {

            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, Math.round(1824/2));
        }

        element.attr('src', newSrc.src);
    });

}
```

Comment: _"trying to run a separate function that works on ready() load"_ `.ready()` not appear at `js` at Question ? Is expected result that first click on `.link` element return different results than following clicks on `.link` element ?

Comment: show us `resizeImage`, where is it defined?

Comment: @WhiteHat Just edited my existing post by adding in the function. Note that the function works fine on the ready call, just not when the ajax html content is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices

First is move the `$ajaxComplete` out of the click handler. Since this is a global event handler there is no need to nest it inside another event handler

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        if (typeof resizeImage == 'function') { 
            console.log('it exists');
            resizeImage(); 
        }else{
            console.log('it doesnt');
        }
});


$( ".link" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    loadSideDrawerContent($(this).attr('href'), 'middle', true, imageSuperZoom);
    openSideDrawer('middle');

});
```

If you have any other ajax in page you may need to add conditionals to check the settings object in `ajaxComplete` or the jXHR object and only resize depending on conditions like url used

---

Alternative would be get rid of `ajaxComplete` and call `resizeImage()` inside the ajax callback that is used in `loadSideDrawerContent()`

For example if `loadSideDrawerContent` uses `load()` as ajax method:

```
$(element).load(url, function(){
     // new html exists now
     resizeImage();
});
```

There are other alternatives as well such as creating custom events and triggering those within various places in app. The callback of custom event would call whatever functions are required.

Or bind `resizeImage()` to `$(window).on('resize`)` and always trigger that event

**NOTE:** Your collection `$mage_resize` will need to be redfined when new elements are inserted. You can't create a cache of elements that don't exist yet